# Why is the preview file not fully loaded after clicking the typesetting button?

Tags: texworks

As the picture shows, some pages are grayed out even after a long time:

[image: PDF not loaded]

These are my preference options:

[image: preferences-preview]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Can you go to `Edit -> Preferences -> Preview tab` and copy an image of your `Preview` settings into your question please? It might be an issue with your screen resolution or render cache, it might be too low

Comment: My render cache is at 256mb, try increasing yours, recompile the document and see if the issue persists

Comment: @JamesT
picture added.I have solved this problem by closing Texworks and reopening. But I think what you're saying is possible. I'll try to learn more about this. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Which version of TeXworks are you using? Do you have an old one, it might be worth upgrading your TeXlive anyway, you're version doesn't have the render cache option so it must be old?